# Three people logic puzzle

Tags: propositional-calculus

There are three doctors. I ask them who can help me? Each doctor says “I am the only one who can help you, because I am the only one who will tell you the truth; the other two doctors are liars!”

I need to create a truth table to see which doctors are telling the truth and what the possible combinations are

So do I have a p, q, and r? Each doctor would have a T, F, F correct? I'm not sure where to go with this and any advice and hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume (though you didn't specifically state it) that each doctor either always tells the truth or always lies.  So if any of the three is a truth-teller, the other two are clearly liars (and this is consistent with their statements).  It's also possible that all three are liars... i.e., all are lying when they claim that they will tell the truth.